# Flag helpful, but post still completely visible?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged this question

[We found a pattern in the random loss of balls in the popular US and European lotteries. For whom this phenomenon can be interesting?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345402/we-found-a-pattern-in-the-random-loss-of-balls-in-the-popular-us-and-european-lo)

as spam and the flag was considered to be helpful. Why is the post still completely visible including the video-link ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My bad. I had just closed the question and did not go directly for deletion.

But with respect to the general aspect of the meta post, a flag can actually be marked helpful yet no visible and/or immediate moderator action be taken regarding it, or even some action can be taken  which was not what the flagger had in mind.